# Can we use the exe files in RedHat 6 as we do in UBUNTU

Tags: rhel, wine

in Ubuntu we can use .exe file using wine software. Is there any such software in RedHat so that we can use .exe files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wine is available for RHEL6 via the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories.  After installing EPEL, you can just:
  `yum install wine`

Answer (score 2):

Wine is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).